# angular observable array with async is not filtering on backspace

Tags: angular, typescript

On value change of the textbox I am getting the data from the server and filtering it. It works great as long as i am typing forward but when i use backspace or delete button, the (input) event does trigger but the server call is not getting executed.

HTML:

```
<div class="searching" >
     <input [readonly]="mode=='EDIT'" formControlName="userNBK" type="text"  
      class="form-control" (input)="getUserData(f.userNBK);" >
     <div *ngIf="showSuggestions == true" (blur)="showSuggestions = false" >
         <ul class="suggestionList">
             <li  *ngFor="let result of aitUsersList | async" 
              (click)="selectUserOption($event,result)" > 
                 {{result.UserId}} | {{result.FirstName}} {{result.LastName}}
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

TS:

```
usersList: Observable<any[]>;

getUserData(input: any) {
this.usersList = 
this.manageService.getUsers("xyz")
  .pipe(
    map ((resp: any[]) => {
        return resp.filter(u => String(u.UserId).toLowerCase().startsWith(String(input.value).toLowerCase()));
    } 
  ));
```

Comment: Never mind, The boolean in html showSuggestions was set to false on select option and was not set to true on (input) change event.Doing so, works fine

Comment: although i have another problem with CSS. in the above input (behaving more like auto-complete) the validation error message is not showing up. Not sure if the is-invalid or invalid-feedback is not getting applied.      <div class="searching" >.....
                             <div *ngIf="submitted && f.userNBK.errors" class="invalid- 
                     feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.userNBK.errors.required">NBK is required</div>
                        </div>

Comment: you need to call `form.updateValueAndValidity()` in  `selectUserOption`